# Highchart Data from HTML table with line series

Tags: highcharts

Heres and example loading from an html table

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/column-parsed/

I want to use that with but also allow for different series type

http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/highcharts/demo/combo-dual-axes/

I was thinking about adding a checkbox column that would indicate a line series but am unsure how to correctly pass that to this function

```
data: {
    table: document.getElementById('datatable')
},
```

Any other links to this feature/api would also be appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a lot of effort just to have some checkboxes in the data table but here you go. I've leveraged the `parsed` callback of the `data` options to parse out the checkboxes and set the series type from them:

```
      data: {
            table: document.getElementById('datatable'),
            parsed: function(){
                var checkBoxes = $('#typeRow input'); //find checkboxes
                for (var i = 0; i < checkBoxes.length; i++){
                    this.columns[i+1].pop(); // remove checkbox row, this will break highcharts parsing
                    if (checkBoxes[i].checked){                                           
                        this.chartOptions.series[i]['type'] = 'line'; //set the series type
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        this.chartOptions.series[i]['type'] = 'column';
                    }
                }
            }
        },
```

Here's a working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/p37F3/1/).

Comment: Beautiful, exactly what I was looking for - I was unaware of the parsed callback. Im working on a page that allows users to create charts on the fly - all the tds will be inputs or a checkbox. My current approach is using angular but it's becoming too cumbersome, especially if I can leverage the ability to load from a table directly since thats basically what Im using angular for -the model is the table row/columns which are tied to a highcharts like data object

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what do you want to do with that checkbox, but in general you can predefine series options like this:

```
    series: [{
        yAxis: 0
    }, {
        type: 'spline',
        yAxis: 1
    }]
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4mb9k/