# Highchart Data from HTML table with <input> values

Tags: javascript, jquery, highcharts

Recently I found this very interesting feature with HighCharts, drawing values from the table.
You can see the example on the following jsfiddle...

http://jsfiddle.net/4mb9k/

That can be found on this [thread.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21294266/highchart-data-from-html-table-with-line-series)

So my question is how can I make the data that is in the table, to be dynamic... Meaning, with `<input>` tag so when the user enters the values, and click the button ... the chart to appear with the inputed values. 
(Doesn't matter the chart type.. column, line, spline... regardless)

You can see my picture in order to understand what I mean...

http://imageshack.com/a/img691/3569/bfz.png

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the attribute contenteditable to the tds, and add a button which will load the graph like this

**HTML**

```
<tr>
    <th>Plums</th>
    <td contentEditable>5</td>
    <td contentEditable>11</td>
</tr>
```

**jQuery**

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('#container').highcharts({//rest of the code
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/4mb9k/4/)